# Script argument as private scope variable

Tags: powershell, scope, command-line-arguments

I can have an argument in a script, which by default becomes a global variable, like this

```
param (
    [string]$argument
)
```

But seemingly I can't control the scope of that variable like this

```
param (
    [string]$private:argument
)
```

In a complex script, with lots of functions in main script, plus other functions in modules, it seems like good practice to limit arguments to Private, but I can't seem to grok how to do it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? `$argument` is not global, btw, it's scoped to the script in which it's defined

Comment: Yes, should have said script not global. But what I want is to have the arguments be private, so I don't have to worry about using the same names in functions in the script. I am leaning towards multiple aliases and a variable name like `$argumentFromCommandLineBecauseReasons`. It's silly, but it would work. I could even perhaps set an actual `$private:argument = $argumentFromCommandLineBecauseReasons` later, then `Remove-Variable argumentFromCommandLineBecauseReasons`, but that's a bit silly.

Comment: You don't need to worry about that :) When you assign to a variable in a nested scope, it'll create a new local variable by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your concern correctly, you have a number of scriptblocks or functions inside the script and you worry that re-using the variable name (in this case `argument`) will lead to messing up the value of the script-level parameter.

### You don't need to worry about that!

At least not if you design your functions sensibly :)

Let's take a look at a sample script:

```bsh
param(
  $argument
)

function innerFunction 
{
  param(
    $innerArgument
  )

  # Now let's write to a new variable, the name of which collides with the script parameter
  $argument = $innerArgument + " and some more stuff"

  Write-Host "`$argument inside innerFunction: '$argument'"
}

Write-Host "`$argument in script: '$argument'"
innerFunction -innerArgument $argument
Write-Host "`$argument in script: '$argument'"
```

Now, if we store this in `test.ps1` and run like this:

```
.\test.ps1 -argument "original argument"
```

We're going to see that the script-level `$argument` variable is completely unaffected by us assigning to an identically-named variable inside the `innerFunction`:

```
$argument in script: 'original argument'
$argument inside innerFunction: 'original argument and some more stuff'
$argument in script: 'original argument'
```

This is by design. When you try to resolve a variable for *reading* (eg. referencing a member: `$argument.Length`), PowerShell will walk up the scope hierarchy until it either finds a suitably named variable, or it reaches the top-most scope without having found anything (effectively resolving the variable reference to `$null` in non-strict mode).

When you attempt to *write* to a variable on the other hand, PowerShell will create a new local variable with the same name if one doesn't exist, *unless* you qualify the scope of it (`$script:argument = ...` will override this copy-on-write behavior).

Comment: Ah, that subtle difference between read and write. I had understood it to be the same behavior in both directions.